# how to crop with node-imagemagick, with a buffer as input, and stdout as output?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, node-imagemagick

I'm using node-imagemagick for the first time.
Disclaimer: I've never used imagemagick, and am not much of a javascript guy. Most experience is in C/C++, Objective-C.

I'm writing a snippet for a server side process that needs to take an input buffer, crop it to an arbitrary bounds, and then output that in stdout.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
var im = require('imagemagick');
...
im.convert([
    binaryDataBlock,
    '-crop',
     cropStr], function(err, stdout, stderr) {....
```

I know my input is good... I've done this with imagemagick's "resize" routine. "cropStr" is a string, "100x100+10+10" -- any arbitrary values go here.

But I still get errors back in stderr:

> ```
>   "result" : "convert: unable to open image `ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½':  @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2587.\nconvert: no decode delegate for this
> ```
>
> image format `ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½' @
>   error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532.\nconvert: option requires an
>   argument`-crop' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1081.\n"

I've tried putting in a "-format" argument, which I thought would set the output format. But then it complains about the argument.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here. It shouldn't be so hard to just crop to an arbitrary rectangle in an image.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated.